# Realm Swift - Object not updating when using modal

Tags: ios, swift, realm

**Working Code**

Inside my tableView's `didSelectRowAt IndexPath` method, I have a call that updates the UserSave model, which is in the default realm. The function is structured like so:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let UserRealm = UserSave()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        UserRealm.articleLink = newsLink[indexPath.row]
        UserRealm.articleBody = newsData[indexPath.row]
        UserRealm.articleTitle = newsTitle[indexPath.row]
        UserRealm.articleAuthor = newsSrc[indexPath.row]
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "webKitSegue", sender: self)
}
```

When this is run, the realm updates with the new values, as it should.

**Problem Code**

I have a second model, UserPrefs, which is also a part of the default realm. It is called inside function `exrefresh(writeToRealm: String)`. The function looks like this:

```
func exrefresh(passed: String) {
    let UserRealm = UserPrefs()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        UserRealm.fetchUrl = passed
    }
    self.refreshControl!.beginRefreshing()
    self.refreshControl!.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
}
```

When this function runs, however, the realm maintains its default values, and does not update with the new one.

**Models**

```
// UserSave

import RealmSwift

class UserSave: Object {
    @objc dynamic var articleTitle = "Default Title"
    @objc dynamic var articleAuthor = "Default Author"
    @objc dynamic var articleLink = "https://example.com"
    @objc dynamic var articleBody = "Default Body"
}

// UserPrefs

import RealmSwift

class UserPrefs: Object {
    @objc dynamic var applicationDark = false
    @objc dynamic var fetchUrl = "https://example.com/"
}
```

**The Issue**

I can update the UserSave model just fine, though I am unable to change the values in UserPrefs, even though both are in the default realm. I use the same code (with the names substituted) to update both models, and only one works properly. I have the .realm file pulled up in the Realm Browser, and am able to watch as UserSave changes. I have followed the guide from [realm.io](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/), and their code only works on one model.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Your example shows `UserRealm.alamofireMode = passed` but `alamofireMode` is not a property of the `UserPrefs` model. Is that an accurate representation of what you are doing?

Comment: Sorry, I edited out “alamofireMode” to try to not use any third-party names. I’ll fix the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question mentions default values. Assuming the objects already exist, you would need to get that object to then be able to update it. Otherwise Realm would not know what object you're referring to.

Here's the code to write an object.

```
func exrefresh(passed: String) {

    let UserRealm = UserPrefs()
    UserRealm.fetchUrl = passed

    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(UserRealm)
    }
}
```

If you are going to only ever have one object of that type, then here's the code to update it.

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let results = realm.objects(UserPrefs.self)
    let theOnlyOne = results.first!

    try! realm.write {
        theOnlyOne.fetchUrl = passed
    }
```

This assumes you have proper error checking to know they object exists before updating.